# DIsable JavaScript password strength meter

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I would like to disable the JQuery password strength meter. I think it's running from the following script.

Can I just remove the script link(s), or would it likely cause validation issues? Should I be un-enquing scripts instead? I am pretty clueless with JS, an example would be greatly appreciated.

```
jQuery(function(s) {
var r = {
    init: function() {
        s(document.body).on("keyup change", "form.register #reg_password, form.checkout #account_password, form.edit-account #password_1, form.lost_reset_password #password_1", this.strengthMeter), s("form.checkout #createaccount").change()
    },
    strengthMeter: function() {
        var e = s("form.register, form.checkout, form.edit-account, form.lost_reset_password"),
            t = s('input[type="submit"]', e),
            a = s("#reg_password, #account_password, #password_1", e),
            o = 1,
            d = a.val();
        r.includeMeter(e, a), o = r.checkPasswordStrength(e, a), d.length > 0 && o < wc_password_strength_meter_params.min_password_strength && !e.is("form.checkout") ? t.attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("disabled") : t.removeAttr("disabled", "disabled").removeClass("disabled")
    },
    includeMeter: function(r, e) {
        var t = r.find(".woocommerce-password-strength");
        "" === e.val() ? (t.remove(), s(document.body).trigger("wc-password-strength-removed")) : 0 === t.length && (e.after('<div class="woocommerce-password-strength" aria-live="polite"></div>'), s(document.body).trigger("wc-password-strength-added"))
    },
    checkPasswordStrength: function(s, r) {
        var e = s.find(".woocommerce-password-strength"),
            t = s.find(".woocommerce-password-hint"),
            a = '<small class="woocommerce-password-hint">' + wc_password_strength_meter_params.i18n_password_hint + "</small>",
            o = wp.passwordStrength.meter(r.val(), wp.passwordStrength.userInputBlacklist()),
            d = "";
        switch (e.removeClass("short bad good strong"), t.remove(), o < wc_password_strength_meter_params.min_password_strength && (d = " - " + wc_password_strength_meter_params.i18n_password_error), o) {
            case 0:
                e.addClass("short").html(pwsL10n["short"] + d), e.after(a);
                break;
            case 1:
            case 2:
                e.addClass("bad").html(pwsL10n.bad + d), e.after(a);
                break;
            case 3:
                e.addClass("good").html(pwsL10n.good + d);
                break;
            case 4:
                e.addClass("strong").html(pwsL10n.strong + d);
                break;
            case 5:
                e.addClass("short").html(pwsL10n.mismatch)
        }
        return o
    }
};
r.init()
});
```

Comment: `r.checkPasswordStrength=function() { return true }`

Comment: Could you please provide an example, perhaps a link to hastebin or the like?

Comment: `r.init();r.checkPasswordStrength=function() { return true }` or replace the code here: `checkPasswordStrength: function() { return true }`

Answer (score 0):

for jquery try

```
$('#your-password-textbox').unbind()
```

It will remove all event handlers for selected element.

Comment: `r.init() ; $('form.register #reg_password, form.checkout #account_password, form.edit-account #password_1, form.lost_reset_password #password_1'). unbind()`